Naming Turing machines paired with input
Is there an established name for pairs $(\langle M \rangle, w)$ of a Turing machine $M$ (or description thereof) together with an input word $w$?
Such pairs often arise as elements of sets for problems, e.g., the halting set $\{(\langle M \rangle, w) : \text{$M$ halts on $w$}\}$ and the acceptance problem $\{(\langle M \rangle, w) : \text{$M$ accepts $w$}\}$, or as input to a universal Turing machine. I need to refer to them often in a proof and repeating the full "pair of ..." becomes unwieldy.

I don't think there is an established name for such pairs, or at least I am not aware of one. In fact, I don't think it would be very helpful or informative to give them names -- as you mentioned, in most cases the pair $\langle M, w \rangle$ is an input to some problem (or language) and it is usually clear from the context that $M$ is a machine and $w$ is its input, so we just refer to the pair as "input for the relevant problem". For example, if $\langle M, w\rangle$ is an input for a reduction, then we write the following to describe how the reduction works:

Given input $\langle M, w \rangle$ for the reduction, the reduction
outputs a machine $\langle T \rangle$ that erases its input and simulates the run of $M$ on $w$...

So I never found a need to give them names as I can write smoothly nonetheless by describing them as an input, and in fact I think it is one of the cases where not giving a name can be more clear, but if you are writing a solution where you need to refer to the pair not as "input" for ambiguity issues, then you can give them whatever name you want, you just need to be consistent about it:

Let $x$ denote the input $\langle M, w\rangle$ for the halting
problem. From here, you can use $x$...

